# React-dnd tutorial - ES5 and ES2015 versions both throwing 'Game.observe is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong here?

'Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _Game.observe) is not a function'

> Game.jsx

```
export function observe(receive) {
    setInterval(() => receive([
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 8),
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)
    ]), 500);
};
```

> index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Board from './Board';
import { observe } from './Game';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

observe(knightPosition => 
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Board knightPosition={knightPosition} />,
        rootEl
    )
);
```

Comment: what line is that referencing in the console

Comment: (0, _Game.observe)(function (knightPosition) {
  return _reactDom2.default.render(_react2.default.createElement(_Board2.default, { knightPosition: knightPosition }), rootEl);
 });

Comment: re-starting the server fixed whatever the issue was - not sure why - HMR was working fine in Webpack without any errors - not sure if should delete this question or keep it in case someone else experiences this but I suppose it's actually a Webpack concern.